# How to add if statements to Ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, dom, select

I do mostly PHP programming, but am stuck on an Ajax problem since I do not know Javascript or Ajax very well at all. I have a combo select menu right now and I would like to hide the third select menu (direction) if the first choice is = 'train'. I read that some browsers do not support the hide function, so the next best option is to keep the third select menu disabled when the second option is chosen assuming the first is train. If it is bus, then the third select menu should still show. Here is my javascript right now and as I'm sure you can imagine it doesn't work.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            if ($("select#agency").attr('value') == 'cta-train') {
        $("select#direction").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }

        $("select#route").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#agency").change(function(){
        $("select#route").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#route").html("<option>wait...</option>");
        var id = $("select#agency option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select_route.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#route").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#route").html(data);
        });
    });
});


    $(document).ready(function(){
            if ($("select#agency").attr('value') == 'cta-train') {
        $("select#direction").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
    else {
        $("select#direction").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#route").change(function(){
        $("select#direction").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#direction").html("<option>wait...</option>");
        var id = $("select#route option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select_direction.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#direction").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#direction").html(data);
        });
    });
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you are trying to make the AJAX POST as soon as the document is ready or should all this activity really be triggered based on some DOM event (select change, button click, etc.)? Also jQuery ``hide() is just fine across browsers. The only `hide()` issue I am aware of was an old Safari bug around trying to execute `hide()` on an element that has not yet been attached to the DOM. Not sure if this is still an issue or not.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I didn't want to to alter the code too much since I just got it working after many hours. As I mentioned, I'm not proficient in any kind of javascript/ajax kind of language, so I just wanted to add a simple few lines of code that would hide the 3rd select based on the 1st select's option. If you have any ideas on how I can possibly do this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you dont want ajax, you want to use javascript to hide a select if another select has a certain element in it. Then use your ajax to file the select as needed.  Here is an example of that http://jsfiddle.net/2FQwQ/

```
<select id='direction'>
    <option value='train'>train</option>
    <option value='car'>car</option>
    <option value='pogo stick'>pogo stick</option>
<select>

<select id='agency'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
<select>

<select id='route'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
<select>
```

Script

```
//SEts your html up to hide the secelt if train
function amITrain() { 
    if ($('#direction').val() === "train"){
        $('#route').hide();
        $('#route').attr('disabled');
     }else{
         $('#route').show();
         $('#route').removeAttr('disabled');
     }        
 }
 $('#direction').change(amITrain);


 //When you get the ajax back, you would fill the select like this, then call the function
 $('#direction').html("<option value='train'>train</option><option value='car'>car</option>     <option value='pogo stick'>pogo stick</option>");
 amITrain();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried it out and tried to alter the code to mine, and it didn't seem to work. I have no idea why it didn't work, but I can't get it to work for whatever reason.

My first select is agency, the second is route, the third is direction, the fourth is stops.

If in agency, they choose train instead of bus, then I'd like the third select (direction) to disappear. If they choose bus, then the third one should still stay there. All select fields are disabled until the one previous changes. 

I apologize for my lack of knowledge in Javascript. I've never really dealt with it b4